# Asp Mvc 3 - Restful web service for consuming on multiple platforms

Tags: web-services, json, asp.net-mvc-3, rest

I am wanting to expose a restful web service for posting and retrieving data, this may be consumed by mobile devices or a web site.

Now the actual creation of the service isn't a problem, what does seem to be a problem is communicating from a different domain.

I have made a simple example service deployed on the ASP.NET development server, which just exposes a simple POST action to send a request with JSON content. Then I have created a simple web page using jquery ajax to send some dummy data over, yet I believe I am getting stung with the same origin policy.

Is this a common thing, and how do you get around it? Some places have mentioned having a proxy on the domain that you always request a get to, but then you cannot use it in a restful manner...

So is this a common issue with a simple fix? As there seem to be plenty of restful services out there that allow 3rd parties to use their service...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How exactly are you "getting stung with the same origin policy"?  From your description, I don't see how it could be relevant.  If `yourdomain.com/some-path/defined-request.json` returns a certain JSON response, then it will return that response regardless of what is requesting the file, unless you have specifically defined required credentials that are not satisfied.

Here is an example of such a web service.  It will return the same JSON object regardless of from where the request is made: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true

Unless I am misunderstanding you (in which case you should clarify your actual problem), the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) doesn't really seem to apply here.

### Update Re: Comment

"*I make a simple HTML page and load it as* `file://myhtmlfilelocation/myhtmlfile.html` *and try to make an ajax request*"

The cause of your problem is that you are using the `file://` URL scheme, instead of the `http://` protocol scheme.   You can find information about this scheme in [Section 3.10 of RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738).  Here is an excerpt:

> The file URL scheme is used to designate files accessible on a particular host computer.  This scheme, unlike most other URL schemes, does not designate a resource that is universally accessible over the Internet.

You should be able to resolve your issue by using the `http://` scheme instead of the `file://` scheme when you make your asynchronous HTTP request.

Comment: I am trying to make a post request (with JSON content) from an android emulator (one domain), to my service (another domain) and with fiddler on there never seems to be any Json content in the header request, same thing if I make a simple HTML page and load it as file://myhtmlfilelocation/myhtmlfile.html and try to make an ajax request, same thing... no data in the header... it was suggested on another question here around model binding not working that as I am doing a post from one domain to another then the same origin policy would apply and it would be classed as cross site scripting.

Comment: @somemvcperson, I have updated my answer.  The issue is that you are using the `file` scheme, which is not intended for accessing files universally over the internet, like a RESTful web service is.  Try using the `http` scheme instead

Comment: Sorry forgot about this question, here is your tick!